# How to register items of a dictionary in ansible

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

Currently i use a ansible script like this:

vars:

```
domains:
  -{domain: 'bla'}
  -{domain: 'blub', copy_to: '/tmp/test/'}
```

tasks:

```
- name: Check certificate date
  command: "..."
  ignore_errors: true
  register: cert_check
  with_items: domains
- name: Request new certificate
  command: "... {{ item.item.domain|quote }}..."
  when: item|failed
  register: output
  with_items: cert_check.results
  notify: Reload Nginx
- name: Copy Certificate
  copy: src=/.../{{ item.item.item.domain }}/cert.pem dest="{{ item.item.item.copy_to }}/"
  when: item.item.item.copy_to is defined and item.changed
  with_items: output.results
```

With each additional step the commands get nastier with `item.item.item` chains to reach original data like the domain.

Is there a way to register the new item of data in the original list like

`domains["{{domain}}"]['expired'] = true` or the have the new variables automatically appended to the first `item` instead of nesting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to register the new item of data in the original list like `domains["{{domain}}"]['expired'] = true`

Nope

> or the have the new variables automatically appended to the first item instead of nesting it?

Nope

Sorry for that short and unsatisfying answer, but unfortunately that's how it is.

If you really have the need for this you could try to work on a [custom filter plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins) which merges the nested results together into a flat list.